# How to delete listview favorite item in android?

Tags: php, android, listview, android-listview

I have problem on code will to delete listview item in favorite page
onClick will show dialog to choose, When choose Delete app is close!

but, listview ite, is hide data in database to delete yet.

//java code

```
if (success == 1) {
        int item = data_shop.get(arg2).getShop_id();
        data_shop.remove(item);
        adapter = new FavShopAdapter(data_shop,getApplicationContext());
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

//php code

```
if (isset($_POST['favorite_shop_id'])) {

    $favorite_shop_id = $_POST['favorite_shop_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM favorite_shop WHERE favorite_shop_id = favorite_shop_id LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `datashop` is the data structure your `FavShopAdapter` is using, you don't have to re-instatiate a new `FavShopAdapter` each time. Just remove the item from the list, and instead of `adapter = new FavShopAdapter(data_shop,getApplicationContext()); listview.setAdapter(adapter);}` you can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` which will update the list for you.

Comment: call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); yet,
but onclick delete app is close & data in database delete not match shop_id when onclick

Comment: There's not enough code/information to answer your question.